# Trying to understand state rendering better: how to fix my audio player

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm having an issue where my audio player only plays if I go into the player component code and press ctrl+s, and it's clearly because the state value with the URL in it doesn't update in time on the call to my handlePlay component.

I know this is an age old issue, I should probably use useEffect, but I've used it before and I can't seem to wrap my head around its correct usage in this scenario, so I really could use some guidance from a patient soul.

First of all, I have an async function that gets a youtubeURL from the backend which references the Youtube API. Here's how I have it simplified so I stop wasting API calls at the moment:

```
      const getSongId = async (title: string, artist: string) => { 
        try {
            
            setYoutubeURL('eA8zugz6G9c')
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error finding album details:", error);
          }
    }
```

Next, I return Play/Pause buttons in the main html and set to display the player if "isPlaying" is set to true:

```
                                           <PlayOrPause handlePlay={handlePlay} isPlaying=  {isPlaying} />
                                            {isPlaying && <Player 
                                                            videoId={youtubeURL && youtubeURL}
                                                            isPlaying={isPlaying}
                                                            songDuration={length}
                                                             />}
```

handlePlay is simple, it just calls the getSongId function above and then sets isPlaying:

```
    const handlePlay = () => {
        
        getSongId(title, artist)
        setIsPlaying(true)
        console.log(youtubeURL)

        console.log('clicked')
      };
```

The console.log(youtubeURL) initially returns null so I know it's not getting re-rendered in time unless I refresh the code as I said earlier. I'm wondering how to solve this and does it have to involve useEffect? I've tried thinking of ways to re-factor my code with it and can't really wrap my head around it well.

For what it's worth, here is the code that gets the audio, and this in fact does use useEffect.

```
    const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {

      if (audio) {

        const playAudio = async () => {
          console.log('entered first time')
          const stream = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stream/${videoId}`);
          const obtainedStream = stream?.data?.streamURL
          audio.src = obtainedStream;
          audio.play();
        };

        playAudio();

      }
    },[])

    return (

      <>
        <audio ref={audioRef}  />

      </>
   
    )
```

This probably isn't a super complicated issue, but I've tried some attempts and am just stuck. If anyone has advice, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: DId you try useRef for youtubeURL? It will be reflected immediately using refs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that seems to be what I wanted. I think I need to learn more how useRef works.

Answer (score 0):

`useRef` will immediately update the value of youtubeURL.(submitting answer that was in comment).